# Change primary audio device via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm attempting to create an audio router app in Electron. I used DetectRTC (https://github.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC) to get the list of audio devices on the computer.

How would I go about changing the Windows default audio device via JavaScript, or is it even possible?

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId

Comment: @Redanium That's quite interesting, though at first glance it seems to only be able to change the output device for the browser itself and not for other applications. I'll have to revisit this project and read more into it though. Thanks, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Forgot about this project but as far as I know it's impossible to control os level audio settings from the browser. I think a good option for this would be to use C# and Windows core libraries, as in [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/sverrirs/d099b34b7f72bb4fb386). Then, the C# could be run within an electron app using [electron-cgi](https://github.com/ruidfigueiredo/electron-cgi#readme).